# Size WPF Browser to its HTML-Content

Tags: c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to show my Flair in a WPF `Browser` Control and size it to the smallest size possible.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
        [...]
        Title="MainWindow" 
        MaxHeight="500" 
        MaxWidth="500"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        Height="86.453" 
        Width="163.44">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="browser"></WebBrowser>        
</Grid>
```

**Here is my Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string CreateHTML()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        builder.AppendLine("<html>");
        builder.AppendLine("<body>");
        builder.AppendLine("<a href=\"http://stackexchange.com/users/5852250\">");
        builder.AppendLine("<img src=\"http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5852250.png?theme=dark\" width=\"208\" height=\"58\" alt=\"profile for Felix D. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\" title=\"profile for Felix D. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\">");
        builder.AppendLine("</a>");
        builder.AppendLine("</body>");
        builder.AppendLine("<html>");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string htmlString = CreateHTML();            
        browser.NavigateToString(htmlString);            
    }        
}
```

I want the browser(to behave like `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` for its content).

I have not found a working solution.

I embedded `Microsoft.mshtml` and tried to get sth. out of `browser.Document` but I did not make any progress so far.

Anyone done sth. similar ?

Comment: you don't need a full web browser, WPF's Image control can point to the flair directly, like this `<Image Name="WB" Height="58" Width="208" Source="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/403671.png?theme=clean" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the size of browser to `0,0` before navigating and then after document load completed, you can set `Width` and `Height` of control to  `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` of document:

```
private void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    browser.Width = ((dynamic)browser.Document).Body.parentElement.scrollWidth;
    browser.Height = ((dynamic)browser.Document).Body.parentElement.scrollHeight;
}
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    browser.Width = 0;
    browser.Height = 0;
}
```

**Note**

**1)** The post is an answer to *Size WPF Browser to its HTML-Content*. If the concern is exactly showing the image, you can rely on an `Image` control as mentioned also in the first comment.

**2)** When showing your flair using [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) control, you need to turn off scrolling by setting `scroll="no"` attribute for `body` tag. Also you need to set `style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\"` for `body` tag. Also remove borders of image by setting `style="border:0px;"` for `img` tag and also maybe some other html and css corrections.

**3)** In a windows with DPI settings set to 125% you need to multiply values by 0.8.

Comment: When testing consider these notes: **1)** In a windows with DPI settings set to `120%` you need to multiply values by `0.8`. **2)** You can test it by navigating to a site like `http://www.google.com`. **3)** To test with your html, change the body tag to `builder.AppendLine("<body scroll=\"no\">");`

Comment: Did you test this ? Because I get a `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` cause the `((dynamic)WebBrowser.Document).Body` is null ....

Comment: The post is an answer to *Size WPF Browser to its HTML-Content*. If the concern is exactly showing your flair, you can rely on an `Image` control: `<Image Source="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5852250.png?theme=dark" Stretch="None"/>`  as mentioned in the first comment. Also if for any reason you want to show the flair in `WebBrowser` control, you need to set `style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\"` and `scroll=\"no\"` for `body` tag. Also you should remove border of image and some tuning to make the content occupy less space as much as possible.

Comment: Alright I got it. I placed your code in `Loaded`not `LoadCompleted`. Somehow the `Height` fits but the `Width`doesn't (Set to 3819) for the flair. But I guess I will get it to work. Thx !

Comment: The width will work after you  set `browser.Width = 0; browser.Height = 0;` in `Navigating` event. Also don't forget to correct the body: `builder.AppendLine("<body scroll=\"no\">");` after running the code, here is the initial result which I get: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAVR5.png)

Answer (score 1):

http://setmy.browsersize.com/ Does this help? This appears to be allowing you to set your browser to a set size for development purposes. I feel this might be a nudge in the right direction?

```
<a href='javascript:(function(w,h){
var n=window,d=document,s=n.screen;
function r(o){      
    n.resizeTo(Number(w)+o,h);
    return n.innerWidth||d.body.clientWidth;
} 
function c(t,u){
    return t>u?(t-u)>>1:0;
}
if(r(1)==r(0)) { 
    if(typeof p=="undefined"||p.closed){
        $("info").className="no_popup";
        p=n.open(n.location.href,
            "resize_popup",
            "menubar,
            toolbar,
            location,
            directories,
            status,
            resizable,
            titlebar,
            ".split(",").join("=yes,")+",
            width="+w+",height="+h+",
            left="+c(s.width,w)+",
            top="+c(s.height,h));
     } else {
            p.focus();
     }
     p.resizeTo(w,h);n=p;
}
if(w>s.width||h>s.height){
    n.moveTo(0,0);
}
})(640, 480);'>640 x 480</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efford but this seems not the solution I am looking for. It's just setting a fixed width/height for the browser. I want the browser so scale with the content. Setting a fixed size is only a solution if I can get the content dimensions.

Comment: i think there are ways of obtaining this information from JQuery - all you then need to do is pass it into the function to set the browser dimensions.

Comment: For instance - $(document).height() returns the height of the HTML document (as opposed to $(window).height() which returns the height of the viewport. same with .width()

Comment: Alright seems like that could work. But (how) can I get this into my `Browser Control` in WPF ? - Note that the html is created in code. There is no file or URL !

Comment: There's always the possibility of writing inline javascript directly into the browser control in the same way that you are writing the HTML - you can even minify the JS to make it fit. I am sure there is a simpler way of doing this though - it call comes down to knowing what the size of the content will be before you render the window. If it really is a "flair" then you will know the size, but I am sure this was used only as an example!

Comment: You are right it's just an example. The flair size is fix :P I will try to include the JS. I'm just not used to it :D

Comment: Also review this question .... might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940671/wpf-how-to-auto-size-webbrowser-inside-a-popup