# Auto-Resize the WinForm Control depending on Content Length

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a WinForm inside which there is a simple WebBrowser control. I want the Form should auto-resize depending on the length of WebBrowser content. If the content is small, the Form should shrink and If the content is big, it should grow.

These are the steps I have taken so for:

1. I have a simple Form inside in which there is a WebBrowser Control.
2. Docked the WebBrowser to Form Control.
3. Set the properties of Form as below:

   - AutoSize: True
   - AutoSizeMode: GrowAndShrink
   - FormBorderStyle: FixedDialog
   - MaximizeBox: False

But still didn't work!

By doing so, the content of the form is completely disappeared.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Down-voter: any specific reason for down voting?

Comment: Looks like you just quit before the job was done.  You have to resize the WebBrowser, the form will follow.  What *exactly* is it that you don't know how to do?   Don't say "everything".

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Size WPF Browser to its HTML-Content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40795036/3110834). It can be applied on a Windows Form application.

Comment: I updated my question?

Comment: @HansPassant, I couldn't find auto-resize for WebBrowser control. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size WPF Browser to its HTML-Content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719182/size-wpf-browser-to-its-html-content)

Comment: @rene it doesn't satisfy my need.

Comment: Why not? What is not working?

Comment: @rene In my scenario, I am using **WinForm** Control in which I have **WebBrowser** and on the other hand, I couldn't see **LoadCompleted** event instead I can see **DocumentCompleted**. I copied the same code there and I was getting the error: **System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' does not contain a definition for 'parentElement'**. Is there any other workaround needs to be done? if yes, please guide.

Comment: Since the width of the text displayed often flows to the width of the browser how will this approach ever work? Are you only working with a well defined set of pages? WebBrowser is pretty limited, have you looked into Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it only somewhat to work if I set `AutoSize` property on the form to false and use the following code in the `DocumentCompleted` event of the webbrowser control, inspired on the [WPF Example from Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795036/578411)

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ClientSize = new Size(
            browser.Document.Body.Parent.ScrollRectangle.Width,
            browser.Document.Body.Parent.ScrollRectangle.Height);    
}
```

Comment: I like using WebBrowser1.Size = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size