# C# embed youtube/videos in your winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube, embed

I have a problem, i added shockwave player to the winform. But it seems that youtube does not support it anymore. So how can i embed a video/youtube video to my winform application?

Comment: Try using WebBrowser Control, then add the embed code you got from YouTube. I have also seen that VLC Player can play YouTube videos from YouTube url. May be you can get some help from their code.

Comment: Already tried, same error.

Comment: Same error means? What is the error you get? You forgot to added error to your question.

Comment: I get something like this: Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control to show embedded youtube video. To do so, put a `WebBrowser` control on a form and the put the following code in form:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var embed = "<html><head>"+
    "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"/>"+
    "</head><body>" +
    "<iframe width=\"300\" src=\"{0}\"" +
    "frameborder = \"0\" allow = \"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" +
    "</body></html>";
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/L6ZgzJKfERM";
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url);
}
```

[image]

**Note**

1. You should make sure you use the correct url. For example for a video that you can see at this address: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6ZgzJKfERM`, the embed url is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/L6ZgzJKfERM`.
2. Also you should make sure the video is allowed to be played as embedded. Some videos are just allowed to play on youtube and after you click on play button you receive this error:

   > This video contains content from XXXXXX. It is restricted from
   >   playback on certain sites or applications.

Comment: This only gave me black screen

Comment: Added `"<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"/>"` to load WebBrowser control in edge mode.

Comment: Greate! Cheers :)

Comment: Any idea how to change the background color to red?

Comment: Or even better make the screen only show the video and not the browser. Also does it freeze sometimes for you aswell?

Comment: For red as backgroupnd color, you should set style for the body: `"</head><body style=\"background-color:red;\">" +`

Comment: For me it plays without any unexpected behavior.

Comment: Cheers for the color change, hm it seems that only that particular video freeze. But the audio is still going.

Comment: To make sure about the solution, you can use the same video which I shared. It's a test video without any audio.

Comment: Well it works perfectly. Any idea how i can stop the video from playing when i switch userControl

Comment: hhmmmm, no. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Ah okay i'll try to figure it out. Any idea how to remove white space inside the webrowser without change the background color? i was able to fix the top white space by adding margin: 0, but i still got on the right and bottom of the web control.

Comment: [It's a WPF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795036/3110834), but it may help you.

Comment: How do I get the embeded player to fit the webbrowser control fully - so there is no white space? My webbrowser control is already set to fill mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
[// MOST IMPORTANT NOTE :
        // c# you have button click you upload video and database
        // You show the video using  DataList Control inside you use Literal control
    // Literal control bind using SqlData Source below link use and bind DataList and Literal Control
```

Visit    https://youtu.be/hXseP_8ZP5I

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
       {                 
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;IntegratedSecurity=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        Response.Write("check "+cn.State);                      
        String link = "<iframe width=\"300\" height = \"200\" src = \"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + TextBox1.Text + "\" frameborder = \"0\" allow = \"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Video(VIDEO_DETAILS,PATH)VALUES('"+"YOUTUBE" +"','" + link +"')"; 
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        cn.Close();
      }
```

visit [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECgnj.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECgnj.png%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/4733879) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!