# How do I embed Youtube video in a vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual basic .NET. I want to embed a youtube video into my application using a url. I already tried using the Shockwave Flash Object, but youtube does not support that anymore. Is there any other way to embed youtube video into vb.net without using the Shockwave Flash Object?

Comment: https://freevideolectures.com/course/3490/visual-basic-net/27

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49047715/102937

Comment: https://hindi.webdunia.com/education-video/x2g14u1

Comment: YouTube doesn't support JavaScript Embedded videos anymore so Shockwave doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is, You can use the Webbrowser for that

```
public function playMyVideo()

WebBroswer1.Navigate("Your Url here")

End Function
```

It should work. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Try to use `Option Strict On` and you will see, where your piece of code has problems.

Comment: Yes, Webbrowser does work, although it may cause some JavaScript errors even with option Strict On

Answer (score 1):

for example live video for vb.net

```
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=youtube_channel_id&eventType=live&type=video&key=your_youtube_data_v3_api_key")

    Dim html As String = "<html><head>"

    html &= "<meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>"

    html &= "<iframe id='video' src= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'?autoplay=1 width='" & WebBrowser1.Width & "' height='" & WebBrowser1.Height & "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"

    html &= "</body></html>"

    Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Format(html)
```